# How to use SSL connection with php?

Tags: php, ssl, ftp

I read about `ftp_ssl_connect()` method, but it doesn't exists. I enabled it in php.ini and also `phpinfo();` say every SSL is enabled. Furthermore, I read php should be recompiled, it requies C++ compiler, etcetcetc which I dont want. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What do you want to connect to, HTTP or FTP? Try using [cURL with SSL](http://www.net24.co.nz/kb/article/AA-00246/21/Shared-Hosting/PHP/How-to-use-CURL-with-PHP-to-get-content-from-SSL-enabled-sites.html).

Comment: FTP additionalTextBecauseStackOverflowDontAllowSmallWords:)

Comment: So, have you tried using cURL?

Comment: cURL can be used as FTP?

Comment: Yes, just [google it](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+curl+ftp)...